# Are we too harsh on this one ?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/6586/270) question is along the lines of [favourite emacs shortcut](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html) or [best video editor](https://askubuntu.com/q/5911/270) or [text editor](https://askubuntu.com/q/804/270) or [php](https://askubuntu.com/q/4246/270)/[ror](https://askubuntu.com/q/3778/270) editor for ubuntu. Many of them are lingering along nicely as community wiki's without accepted answers capturing the opinions and suggestions of the community.

Compared to editors, games, IMO, may not even incite so much flame-wars and would rather educate on the variety and options avaialble. Most of us have a single text editor we can't live without, with games on the other hand the more the better I guess.

Finally, the fact that there is IRC or forums shouldn't mean people should go there instead. For me, it is natural to aspire for the google search for favourite ubuntu games to also land in askubuntu.com.

I agree it should be community wiki, but not something deserving to be closed. Is this some new rule we have taken to up to ban all questions that invite such opinions ? Aren't we being too harsh here ?

Comment: It's definitely tricky. My favourite of these questions is my own on Backup tools - http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-ubuntu-backup-tools

Answer (score 6):

I am of two minds. I think "best IDE" type threads are kind of useless, since there's 15 years of those discussions already all over the internet.

On the other hand I did find some rather nice entries in those threads, and I think if we get the quality right then it can be useful. [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4922/gui-twitter-clients-what-are-my-options) is on it's way to becoming the best GUI twitter page already for example.

However I think a "best game" one is far too open ended. You'd end up with every game in the archive. Perhaps something more narrow?

Comment: There is also a gaming centric site available on SE: http://gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Marco, most of the games discussed on there are on consoles or won't run on a Linux PC.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately that wasn't a question - and what the title was extremely subjective considering the wide range of games out there. If the poster has limited the scope of the question to native games, games in Wine, genre of games, and made it more constructive. Then it would possibly have a better chance. However, this also dabbles more in the world of [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and not so much Ubuntu.

I've reopened the question with some modifications to give it a chance!

Comment: I agree... and in the past we have asked (commented) such questions to be edited so that they are less subjective. I don't think the OP in this case has much SO/SE experience, so it might be a genuine mistake. I feel we should reopen the question and give OP a chance. However, I don't mean to take this any further if you disagree.

Comment: @koushik I'm going to be the first to say: on this site I am a nobody - just a person whos goal is to align their will with the rest of the community. Given the amount of push on this one question I'm willing to revisit it and give it another shot (since not many people can vote to reopen).

Comment: thanks. Really appreciate it. You and the rest of the moderators are doing a wonderful job of running this site. Keep it up.