# How to ask a question with a template already created for answers?

Tags: support, asking-questions

[This question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1089/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011) has a template already created for answering it. That is, instead of the answer textbox starting out empty, it starts out with this text in it:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

  [1]: http://image-url
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Now, granted, a template like this would rarely be suitable...especially outside of `meta`. But...how is that done? Is this just a special feature that only moderators or Stack Exchange employees can use?

Comment: I assume by administrators you mean moderators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Community promotion ad posts are an anomaly in that they aren't really questions in the SE sense -- it's just a way for us to get the ads rolling without writing a whole separate UI for them**

*No one can template answers*, because any answer that would benefit from this is a **BAD QUESTION**.

The [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask) specifically warns against asking questions for which every answer would be equally valid (a poll or list of anything is an example).

Ask Ubuntu is a place to *share expertise* and *solve problems*, not a place to run polls.  Our format isn't good at it, and these types of questions get in the way of the things our format *is* good at.  There are plenty of places for aimless discussion, but Ask Ubuntu is valuable precisely because it isn't like those places.

Comment: While this is true for StackExchange as a whole, Ask Ubuntu is currently permissive to questions in the `software-recommendation` category (*See [Are we too harsh on this one?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/500/are-we-too-harsh-on-this-one)* ). The topic of whether we *should* be permissive put aside, these questions would benefit from templates.

Comment: @j-johan-edwards Recommendation questions would not benefit from templates. A good answer to a recommendation question is not a single item, it makes several proposals and indicates the benefits and limitations of each, so that the asker can make an informed choice.