# How do I move a Ask Ubuntu "list question" to the Ubuntu wiki?

Tags: discussion

I have some questions on Ask Ubuntu that is being closed for being lists (the FAQ doesn't allow it) and I want to move them to the Ubuntu wiki since I think they are good lists and still useful.

Examples:

- [Where can I find websites that list games for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/39382/10698)
- [What web browsers are there for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/44326/10698)

Comment: Are you wondering about if there's license issues of migrating it to the wiki or how to reformat it for the wiki?

Comment: @N.N About formating, since I don't know if Ishould copy paste it, line it as a question with an answer or just list the answers?

Comment: To read everything and rewrite it all as a coherent piece of text seems most fitting to the format I've seen on the Ubuntu wiki.

Comment: So what you mean is that I should take the list answers and make them into one list on the wiki, with as much info as possible from the answers. or?

Comment: Something like that. Reformulate everything into one text. This might mean to change some things so that everything fits together and remove some things that are not necessary.